# julia: UndefRefError: access to undefined reference

Tags: julia

I'm trying to create a POMDP model and solve it. But during the solving process, I get this error:

```
  Got exception outside of a @test
  UndefRefError: access to undefined reference
  Stacktrace:
    [1] getindex
      @ ./array.jl:801 [inlined]
    [2] iterate
      @ ./array.jl:777 [inlined]
    [3] iterate
      @ ./iterators.jl:159 [inlined]
    [4] write(io::IOStream, pomdp::AccPOMDP)
      @ POMDPFiles ~/.julia/packages/POMDPFiles/vOfxh/src/write.jl:64
    [5] #3
      @ ~/.julia/packages/POMDPSolve/LzAMF/src/solver.jl:175 [inlined]
    [6] open(::POMDPSolve.var"#3#4"{AccPOMDP}, ::String, ::Vararg{String, N} where N; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
      @ Base ./io.jl:330
    [7] open
      @ ./io.jl:328 [inlined]
    [8] solve(solver::POMDPSolveSolver, pomdp::AccPOMDP)
      @ POMDPSolve ~/.julia/packages/POMDPSolve/LzAMF/src/solver.jl:174
    [9] macro expansion
      @ ~/jl/acc/acc_dev.jl:556 [inlined]
   [10] macro expansion
      @ /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Test/src/Test.jl:1151 [inlined]
   [11] top-level scope
      @ ~/jl/acc/acc_dev.jl:546
   [12] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
      @ Base ./Base.jl:386
   [13] exec_options(opts::Base.JLOptions)
      @ Base ./client.jl:285
   [14] _start()
      @ Base ./client.jl:485
```

I'm not so familiar with the Julia Stacktrace, so could you please help me fix this problem?

Comment: It looks like this will require specialized knowledge of the POMDP package in question. Which package(s) are you using? I'm assuming one or more from https://github.com/JuliaPOMDP/

Comment: Yes, I'm using a lot of packages in it. Here's my code https://github.com/beamiter/julia-repo/tree/main/acc and it's easy to re-generate the problem.

Comment: It seemes to be my POMDP-related code problem and I've already fixed it.

Comment: If it's something you think others could learn from, you could answer your own question here with the solution

Comment: Hi, It seems like you have resolved your problem, if you don't know about it already you might want to look at https://github.com/sisl/AutomotiveSimulator.jl and https://github.com/sisl/AutomotiveVisualization.jl which is replacing AutoViz and can be use to build Automotive related POMDPs

Answer (score 0):

Caused by stateindex(...) and states(...) wrong implementation in my POMDP model. But after I fix this ans start to solve the problem, the solving just kept run and finally failed. Just want to complain, Julia POMDP is really hard to use in reality...